# can decoder only large language model be fine tuned to perform well at semantic similarity search?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transformer, llm

BERT based models are Encoder only which are well suited for text classification, and Semantic Text similarity search (If fine-tuned via sBERT). I want to know whether decoder only models like Llama2, GPT can be fine-tuned to do well on STS benchmark. If yes, does it perform better than fine-tuning encoder-only models?